# Models giving 100% accuracy, random forest, logit, C5.0?

Tags: r, regression, random-forest, prediction, logarithm

When trying to fit models to predict the outcome "death" I am having a 100% accuracy, this is obviously wrong. Could someone tell me what am I missing?

```
library(caret)
set.seed(100)
intrain <- createDataPartition(riskFinal$death,p=0.6, list=FALSE)
training_Score <- riskFinal[intrain,]
testing_Score <- riskFinal[-intrain,]

control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", repeats=3, number=5)
#C5.0 decision tree
set.seed(100)
modelC50 <- train(death~., data=training_Score, method="C5.0",trControl=control)
summary(modelC50)

#Call:
#C5.0.default(x = structure(c(3, 4, 2, 30, 4, 12, 156, 0.0328767150640488, 36, 0.164383560419083, 22,
# 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
# 0, 0, 0, 0, 


#C5.0 [Release 2.07 GPL Edition]    Tue Aug  4 10:23:10 2015
#-------------------------------

#Class specified by attribute `outcome'

#Read 27875 cases (23 attributes) from undefined.data

#21 attributes winnowed
#Estimated importance of remaining attributes:

#-2147483648%  no.subjective.fevernofever

#Rules:

#Rule 1: (26982, lift 1.0)
#   no.subjective.fevernofever <= 0
#   ->  class no  [1.000]

#Rule 2: (893, lift 31.2)
#   no.subjective.fevernofever > 0
#   ->  class yes  [0.999]

#Default class: no


#Evaluation on training data (27875 cases):

#           Rules     
#     ----------------
#       No      Errors

#        2    0( 0.0%)   <<


#      (a)   (b)    <-classified as
#     ----  ----
#    26982          (a): class no
#            893    (b): class yes


#   Attribute usage:

#   100.00% no.subjective.fevernofever


#Time: 0.1 secs


confusionMatrix(predictC50, testing_Score$death)

#Confusion Matrix and Statistics

#          Reference
#Prediction    no   yes
#       no  17988     0
#       yes     0   595

#               Accuracy : 1          
#                 95% CI : (0.9998, 1)
#    No Information Rate : 0.968      
#    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2.2e-16  

#                  Kappa : 1          
# Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA         

#            Sensitivity : 1.000      
#            Specificity : 1.000      
#         Pos Pred Value : 1.000      
#         Neg Pred Value : 1.000      
#             Prevalence : 0.968      
#         Detection Rate : 0.968      
#   Detection Prevalence : 0.968      
#      Balanced Accuracy : 1.000      

#       'Positive' Class : no
```

For the Random Forest model

```
set.seed(100)
modelRF <- train(death~., data=training_Score, method="rf", trControl=control)
predictRF <- predict(modelRF,testing_Score)
confusionMatrix(predictRF, testing_Score$death)

#Confusion Matrix and Statistics
#
#          Reference
#Prediction    no   yes
#       no  17988     0
#       yes     0   595

#               Accuracy : 1          
#                 95% CI : (0.9998, 1)
#    No Information Rate : 0.968      
#    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2.2e-16  

#                  Kappa : 1          
# Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA         

#            Sensitivity : 1.000      
#            Specificity : 1.000      
#         Pos Pred Value : 1.000      
#         Neg Pred Value : 1.000      
#             Prevalence : 0.968      
#         Detection Rate : 0.968      
#   Detection Prevalence : 0.968      
#      Balanced Accuracy : 1.000      

#       'Positive' Class : no         

predictRFprobs <- predict(modelRF, testing_Score, type = "prob")
```

For the Logit model

```
set.seed(100)
modelLOGIT <- train(death~., data=training_Score,method="glm",family="binomial", trControl=control)
summary(modelLOGIT)

#Call:
#NULL

#Deviance Residuals: 
#       Min          1Q      Median          3Q         Max  
#-2.409e-06  -2.409e-06  -2.409e-06  -2.409e-06   2.409e-06  

#Coefficients:
#                             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
#(Intercept)                -2.657e+01  7.144e+04   0.000    1.000
#age.in.months               3.554e-15  7.681e+01   0.000    1.000
#temp                       -1.916e-13  1.885e+03   0.000    1.000
#genderfemale                3.644e-14  4.290e+03   0.000    1.000
#no.subjective.fevernofever  5.313e+01  1.237e+04   0.004    0.997
#palloryes                  -1.156e-13  4.747e+03   0.000    1.000
#jaundiceyes                -2.330e-12  1.142e+04   0.000    1.000
#vomitingyes                 1.197e-13  4.791e+03   0.000    1.000
#diarrheayes                -3.043e-13  4.841e+03   0.000    1.000
#dark.urineyes              -6.958e-13  1.037e+04   0.000    1.000
#intercostal.retractionyes   2.851e-13  1.003e+04   0.000    1.000
#subcostal.retractionyes     7.414e-13  1.012e+04   0.000    1.000
#wheezingyes                -1.756e-12  1.091e+04   0.000    1.000
#rhonchiyes                 -1.659e-12  1.074e+04   0.000    1.000
#difficulty.breathingyes     4.496e-13  6.504e+03   0.000    1.000
#deep.breathingyes           1.086e-12  7.075e+03   0.000    1.000
#convulsionsyes             -1.294e-12  6.424e+03   0.000    1.000
#lethargyyes                -4.338e-13  6.188e+03   0.000    1.000
#unable.to.sityes           -4.284e-13  8.118e+03   0.000    1.000
#unable.to.drinkyes          7.297e-13  6.507e+03   0.000    1.000
#altered.consciousnessyes    2.907e-12  1.071e+04   0.000    1.000
#unconsciousnessyes          2.868e-11  1.505e+04   0.000    1.000
#meningeal.signsyes         -1.177e-11  1.570e+04   0.000    1.000

#(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

#    Null deviance: 7.9025e+03  on 27874  degrees of freedom
#Residual deviance: 1.6172e-07  on 27852  degrees of freedom
#AIC: 46

#Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 25

#predictLOGIT<-predict(modelLOGIT,testing_Score)

confusionMatrix(predictLOGIT, testing_Score$death)

#Confusion Matrix and Statistics

#          Reference
#Prediction    no   yes
#       no  17988     0
#       yes     0   595

#               Accuracy : 1          
#                 95% CI : (0.9998, 1)
#    No Information Rate : 0.968      
#    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2.2e-16  

#                  Kappa : 1          
# Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA         

#            Sensitivity : 1.000      
#            Specificity : 1.000      
#         Pos Pred Value : 1.000      
#         Neg Pred Value : 1.000      
#             Prevalence : 0.968      
#         Detection Rate : 0.968      
#   Detection Prevalence : 0.968      
#      Balanced Accuracy : 1.000      

#       'Positive' Class : no
```

The data before slicing was:

```
str(riskFinal)
#'data.frame':  46458 obs. of  23 variables:
# $ age.in.months         : num  3 3 4 2 1.16 ...
# $ temp                  : num  35.5 39.4 36.8 35.2 35 34.3 37.2 35.2 34.6 35.3 ...
# $ gender                : Factor w/ 2 levels "male","female": 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
# $ no.subjective.fever   : Factor w/ 2 levels "fever","nofever": 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 ...
# $ pallor                : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 ...
# $ jaundice              : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
# $ vomiting              : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
# $ diarrhea              : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
# $ dark.urine            : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
# $ intercostal.retraction: Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 ...
# $ subcostal.retraction  : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 ...
# $ wheezing              : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ rhonchi               : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
# $ difficulty.breathing  : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 ...
# $ deep.breathing        : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 ...
# $ convulsions           : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 ...
# $ lethargy              : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
# $ unable.to.sit         : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
# $ unable.to.drink       : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
# $ altered.consciousness : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
# $ unconsciousness       : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
# $ meningeal.signs       : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 ...
# $ death                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 ...
```

**EDIT**: based on the comments, I realized that the no.subjective.fever variable had the exactly same values as the target variable death, so I excluded it from the model. Then I got even stranger results:

RANDOM FOREST

```
set.seed(100)
        nmodelRF<- train(death~.-no.subjective.fever, data=training_Score, method="rf", trControl=control)
        summary(nmodelRF)
        npredictRF<-predict(nmodelRF,testing_Score)
> confusionMatrix(npredictRF, testing_Score$death)


 # Confusion Matrix and Statistics
   # 
   #           Reference
   # Prediction    no   yes
   #        no  17988   595
   #        yes     0     0
   #                                           
   #               Accuracy : 0.968           
   #                  95% CI : (0.9653, 0.9705)
   #     No Information Rate : 0.968           
   #     P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.5109          
   #                                           
   #                   Kappa : 0               
   #  Mcnemar's Test P-Value : <2e-16          
   #                                           
   #             Sensitivity : 1.000           
   #             Specificity : 0.000           
   #          Pos Pred Value : 0.968           
   #          Neg Pred Value :   NaN           
   #              Prevalence : 0.968           
   #          Detection Rate : 0.968           
   #    Detection Prevalence : 1.000           
   #       Balanced Accuracy : 0.500           
   #                                           
   #        'Positive' Class : no 


Logit

set.seed(100)
        nmodelLOGIT<- train(death~.-no.subjective.fever, data=training_Score,method="glm",family="binomial", trControl=control)
        >summary(nmodelLOGIT)

# Call:
#         NULL
# 
# Deviance Residuals: 
#         Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
# -1.5113  -0.2525  -0.2041  -0.1676   3.1698  
# 
# Coefficients:
# Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept)                2.432065   1.084942   2.242 0.024984 *  
#age.in.months             -0.001047   0.001293  -0.810 0.417874    
#temp                      -0.168704   0.028815  -5.855 4.78e-09 ***
#genderfemale              -0.053306   0.070468  -0.756 0.449375    
#palloryes                  0.282123   0.076518   3.687 0.000227 ***
#jaundiceyes                0.323755   0.144607   2.239 0.025165 *  
#vomitingyes               -0.533661   0.082948  -6.434 1.25e-10 ***
#diarrheayes               -0.040272   0.080417  -0.501 0.616520    
#dark.urineyes             -0.583666   0.168787  -3.458 0.000544 ***
#intercostal.retractionyes -0.021717   0.129607  -0.168 0.866926    
#subcostal.retractionyes    0.269588   0.128772   2.094 0.036301 *  
#wheezingyes               -0.587940   0.150475  -3.907 9.34e-05 ***
#rhonchiyes                -0.008565   0.140095  -0.061 0.951249    
#difficulty.breathingyes    0.397394   0.087789   4.527 5.99e-06 ***
#deep.breathingyes          0.399302   0.098761   4.043 5.28e-05 ***
#convulsionsyes             0.132609   0.094038   1.410 0.158491    
#lethargyyes                0.338599   0.089934   3.765 0.000167 ***
#unable.to.sityes           0.452111   0.104556   4.324 1.53e-05 ***
#unable.to.drinkyes         0.516878   0.089685   5.763 8.25e-09 ***
#altered.consciousnessyes   0.433672   0.123288   3.518 0.000436 ***
#unconsciousnessyes         0.754012   0.136105   5.540 3.03e-08 ***
#meningeal.signsyes         0.188823   0.161088   1.172 0.241130    
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
# 
# Null deviance: 7902.5  on 27874  degrees of freedom
# Residual deviance: 7148.5  on 27853  degrees of freedom
# AIC: 7192.5
# 
# Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6

npredictLOGIT<-predict(nmodelLOGIT,testing_Score)
        >confusionMatrix(npredictLOGIT, testing_Score$death)

# Confusion Matrix and Statistics
# 
# Reference
# Prediction    no   yes
# no  17982   592
# yes     6     3
# 
# Accuracy : 0.9678          
# 95% CI : (0.9652, 0.9703)
# No Information Rate : 0.968           
# P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.5605          
# 
# Kappa : 0.009           
# Mcnemar's Test P-Value : <2e-16          
# 
# Sensitivity : 0.999666        
# Specificity : 0.005042        
# Pos Pred Value : 0.968127        
# Neg Pred Value : 0.333333        
# Prevalence : 0.967981        
# Detection Rate : 0.967659        
# Detection Prevalence : 0.999516        
# Balanced Accuracy : 0.502354        
# 
# 'Positive' Class : no
```

Comment: how many data points do you have in your training data, in your cross validation data and in your test data? and is the data of all 3 sets independent?

Comment: A 100% accuracy in a C5.0 model means almost certainly that you have erroneously included the target variable in the training/test data of your model. The code then discards all other variables as it recognizes that a perfect classification is obtained by only observing the target variable.

Comment: Or, if not the target variable itself, maybe one or more of the predictors change systematically when death is observed (e.g., temperature goes to 0), so you have leakage of the target into the predictors. You might try lagging the predictors one period (or leading the target) and seeing if you get more realistic results that way.

Comment: I've checked my predictors and saw that one of the variables had the exactly same values as the outcome, so I took it out from the model, but I got results with almost 100% accuracy, almost 0% Specifity and almost 100% sensibility. what is wrong?

Comment: I hope that I'm not adding some confusion, but I have a question concerning your edit: if you remove `no.subjective.fever` in the training set, shouldn't that variable also be discarded from the `testing_Score` set used for the prediction?

Answer (score 2):

The 100% accuracy results are probably not correct. I assume that they are due to the fact that the target variable (or another variable with essentially the same entries as the target variable, as pointed out in a comment by @ulfelder) is included in the training set and in the test set. Usually these columns need to be removed during the model building and testing process, since they represent the target that describes the classification, whereas the train/test data should only contain information that (hopefully) leads to a correct classification according to the target variable.

You could try the following:

```
target <- riskFinal$death
set.seed(100)
intrain <- createDataPartition(riskFinal$death,p=0.6, list=FALSE)
training_Score <- riskFinal[intrain,]
testing_Score <- riskFinal[-intrain,]
train_target <- training_Score$death
test_target <- test_Score$death
training_Score <- training_Score[,-which(colnames(training_Score)=="death")]
test_Score <- test_Score[,-which(colnames(test_Score)=="death")]
modelRF <- train(training_Score, train_target, method="rf", trControl=control)
```

Then you could proceed like you did before, noting that the target "death" is stored in the variables `train_target` and `test_target`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the caret package excludes the target variable from the model with the train() function. just to be sure I did what you suggested and got the exactly same results

Comment: In a previous edit I pointed out that I'm not familiar with the caret package. The comments that I made refer to packages that I have been working with, like C50. I hope that you find the reason if my analysis is not correct.

Comment: Following your comment I have rephrased the text in a more prudent way. Even if this answer does not provide the solution to your specific problem, I would like to keep it posted because I think it might be useful to others. I once made such a mistake, and it took me some time to figure out what went wrong.